# Passing URL through Command Line(C++)

Tags: c++, linux, command, command-line-arguments

I have c++ code which parses 2 command line arguments and prints the arguments. One of the argument is an URL of google search. I paste the code below

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << argv[1] << argv[2] << "\n";

}
```

When I pass URL through command line after compilation as below,

```
./demo 1 https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu&q=size%20of%20unsigned%20char%20array%20c%2B%2B&oq=length%20of%20unsigned%20char*%20arra&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.13353j0j7
```

I get the output as,

```
[1] 8680
[2] 8681
[3] 8682
[4] 8683
[5] 8684
[6] 8685
[7] 8686
[2]   Done                    ion=1
[3]   Done                    espv=2
[4]   Done                    ie=UTF-8
[6]-  Done                    q=size%20of%20unsigned%20char%20array%20c%2B%2B
```

It looks like there has been some internal splitting of the string. Is there any way I can retrieve the entire string?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: I think there has been splitting of the string with delimiter '&'

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote it. Otherwise `&` gets interpreted by the shell as "invoke what's on the left of `&` in background".

I took the privilege of replacing your program with `echo`.

Good:

```
$ echo "https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu&q=size%20of%20unsigned%20char%20array%20c%2B%2B&oq=length%20of%20unsigned%20char*%20arra&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.13353j0j7"
https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu&q=size%20of%20unsigned%20char%20array%20c%2B%2B&oq=length%20of%20unsigned%20char*%20arra&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.13353j0j7
```

Bad:

```
$ echo https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu&q=size%20of%20unsigned%20char%20array%20c%2B%2B&oq=length%20of%20unsigned%20char*%20arra&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.13353j0j7
[1] 21705
[2] 21706
https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2
[3] 21707
[4] 21708
[5] 21709
[6] 21710
[7] 21711
[1]   Done                    echo https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2
[2]   Done                    ion=1
[3]   Done                    espv=2
[4]   Done                    ie=UTF-8
[5]   Done                    client=ubuntu
[6]-  Done                    q=size%20of%20unsigned%20char%20array%20c%2B%2B
[7]+  Done                    oq=length%20of%20unsigned%20char*%20arra
```

Comment: Thank You for your quick reply... :) it worked beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the argument, and you should use single quotes, `'`, in order to stop your shell from attempting to evaluate anything inside it.

What happens is that every ampersand, "&", on your command line launches a background process.

The first process is `./demo 1 https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2`, and all the following are assignments to variables.

You can see from the output (it looks like you didn't post all of it)

```
[1] 8680
[2] 8681
[3] 8682
[4] 8683
[5] 8684
[6] 8685
[7] 8686
[2]   Done                    ion=1
[3]   Done                    espv=2
[4]   Done                    ie=UTF-8
[6]-  Done                    q=size%20of%20unsigned%20char%20array%20c%2B%2B
```

that background process 2 is `ion=1` (pid 8681), process 3 (pid 8682) is `espv=2`, and so on.